# Trying to delete an entry from a structure array in C#. Getting conflicting information?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I have been researching this topic and got conflicting answers. Any help is appreciated.
For an assignment, I am instructed to create a structure of arrays. I am trying to delete an entry in one case, and change in another. This is supposed to be by one of the fields and not by index number.

```
var countOfEmployees = 0;
var employees = new EmployeeData[100];
Console.Write("Please enter employee you want to delete:");
string deleteEmployee = Console.ReadLine();
bool deleted = false;
for (int x = 0; x < countOfemployees; x++)
{

 if (items[x].ItemNumber == deleteItemNumber)

  {
 deleted = true;   

  }
if (true)
 {

//code goes here                                       

  }
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: We can't see where you have created deleteItemNumber.

Comment: You can't delete from an array. You'd need to convert to a list first.

Comment: You should at least post a sample that people can copy/paste. As it is, your code doesn't compile.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. This is my first post here, and I will do as you say next time. I did find

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an array, you might be able to delete the value from the place holder, but you will not be able to remove the actual item without some footwork.

Basically, what you can do is: Find the value you've searched for, and replace it with a null and treat it orrespondingly in every other function.

Option 2 would be to remove the item and then use a function that would "shift" all the values with a higher index upwards.

Option 3 is to use the advanced functions C#/.NET has to offer with collections, create a List, remove the item and cast back to an array.

```
var employees = new EmployeeData[100];
var list = employees.ToList();
int index=-1;

//search through in a loop (won't write it here)...
    index = x; //get the index in your list then break the loop
    break; //end the loop


list.RemoveAt(index); //delete the spot outside the loop
employees=list.ToArray();
```

Of course there's checks needed if the search didn't find anything, but i think you can manage to implement that without my help.
And this is of course me assuming that there's only ONE entry with that kind of value in the array.
If it's not, you're gonna have to loop through and erase them until the search doesn't find anything anymore.

Comment: Thank you. This was extremely helpful!

Comment: one more question. I implemented your 3rd suggestion, and while it works perfectly leaves behind a null value. Would it be better to clear the null while it is still a list? Or should I do that after it goes back to array? (or does this matter and am I overthinking this?)

Comment: I was able to take away the null entry by adding var numberOfEmployees= 0; and then at the end of the block added numberOfEmployees--

Comment: I would recommend to overwrite the ``countOfEmployees`` with the value from ``list.Count``